# How can web services be independant from the DAL implementations?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, architecture

I am working on [a project](https://github.com/gcolbert/ACEM/) that can be used with two data access layer implementations :

- Either a graph database,
- Either a relational database.

The choice of the implementation depends of the Spring active profile when Tomcat starts (either spring.profiles.active=graph-database, or spring.profiles.active=relational-database). This works great.

I'm in the process of adding REST services on the service layer. For now, I have only annotated the [retrieveAllCategories](https://github.com/gcolbert/ACEM/blob/master/ACEM-domain-services/src/main/java/eu/ueb/acem/services/ResourcesServiceImpl.java#L379) method, which responds to the "/rest/resources/categories" URL. It displays JSON as expected, but my problem is that, when the server uses the DAL graph database implementation, the output is not the same than when it uses the relational database module.

The difference relates to the collections of objects associated with the "ResourceCategory" class. I already had to annotate my "JPA" domain beans with annotations like `@JsonIgnore`, `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` ([example](https://github.com/gcolbert/ACEM/blob/master/ACEM-dal-relational-database/src/main/java/eu/ueb/acem/domain/beans/jpa/jaune/ResourceCategoryEntity.java#L80)) to avoid infinite recursivity. This is quite a long and boring thing to do, and I would prefer not to have to do this all over my project.

**My question** : is there a better way (than annotating every "relational database" bean very patiently) to ensure that my web services will serve the exactly same data, independently of the DAL implementation used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common solution to your problem is to use Data Transfer Objects (DTO).

Basically, you create a new class which represents exactly how the commands/responses of your web service should be.

Then, it is only a matter of converting to and from that class.

Example:

```
public class JpaMovie {

    @OneToMany
    private List<Actor> actors;

    // Whatever you need in JPA DAL.
}

public class GraphMovie {
    // Whatever you need in Graph DAL.
}

public class MovieDTO {
    // Structure of the web service response.
    // Always convert to this type before returning.
    // This way, no matter the DAL, your response
    // structure will always be the same.
}
```

And here how to use them in your case (you are using setter/getter interfaces for your domain model):

```
@Controller
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;

    @RequestMapping("/movies")
    public @ResponseBody MovieDTO findById(@RequestParam String id) {
        MovieInterface movie = movieService.findById(id);
        return MovieDTO.from(movie);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm not sure that I understand how I can return the DTO objects from my current "services" layer? Do using DTO objects imply that I must create a new "web-services" sub-project?

Comment: @GrégoireColbert you don't need to change the return type of your "services" layer. I saw on your repository that you use interfaces for getters/setters on your domain model, so you only need to change the return type of your controllers. See the example that I added at the end of the answer.

Comment: Do you think that this would make sense to create a new Maven module that would contain the Data Transfer Objects and the web-services "controllers"?

Comment: @GrégoireColbert yes, you can put all your DTOs in another module, and share that module with the consumer (client) of your API. Those classes are the *model* of the communication: a *contract* of sorts. Yes, you could do that, but it is not mandatory. About the web-services "controllers", I assumed you are using Spring MVC since you tagged the question as `Spring`. Usually I put my controllers in another package in the same module as the application, but it is up to you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to implement a new module, I think web services are somewhat like a new presentation layer.